# If $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ are integers and $a_1a_2\cdots a_n=0$ then $a_i=0$ for some $1\le i \le n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

If $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ are integers and $a_1a_2\cdots a_n=0$ then $a_i=0$ for some $1\le i \le n$

I'm trying to prove this by using induction

We can prove this for $n=1$

means $a_1=0$ this implies true for $n=1$

Suppose this is true for $n=k$

ie $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ are integers and $a_1a_2\cdots a_n=0 $ then $a_k=0$ for some $1\le k \le n$

we have to prove for $n=k+1, 1\le k+1 \le n$

I am not getting the idea from here any idea please thank you

Comment: Just write $a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \dots \cdot a_n \cdot a_{n+1} = (a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \dots \cdot a_n) \cdot a_{n+1}$ and apply the result for $n=2$ and the induction hypothesis.

Comment: There is no reason to restrict to integers.  Also, proof by contraposition is much simpler than induction here, but maybe you want the practice.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net There is no "result for $n=2$" yet, we only know the base case $n=1$.

Comment: @WolfgangKais The case $n=2$ follows from usual results on the integers.

Answer (score 2):

The induction statement is:

If $a_1\cdot a_2\cdots a_n $ are integers and $a_1\cdot a_2\cdot \ldots \cdot a_n=0,$ then $a_i=0$ for some $1\le i \le n.\qquad P(n)$

I prove the induction hypothesis, that is, if $P(n)$ is true then $P(n+1)$ is true - by way of contradiction. So assume $P(n)$ is true, and suppose $P(n+1)$ is false.

The there exist integers $a_1,\ a_2, \ldots,\ a_{n+1}$ such that  $a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot a_{n+1}=0\quad (1) ,\ $ and $\ a_i \neq 0\ \forall i\in \{1,2,\ldots,n+1\}\quad (2).\ $ Since $P(n)$ is true, the contrapositive of $P(n)$ is true, and so $a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot a_n \neq 0.$ Thus we are permitted to divide both sides of equation $(1)$ by $a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot a_n$ to get $ a_{n+1} = 0\times \frac{1}{a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot a_n} = 0,\ $ contradicting $(2).$ The assumption that $P(n+1)$ is false has lead to a contradiction: we therefore conclude that $P(n+1)$ is true.

Comment: I feel like this is over-engineered with the use of proof-by-contradiction, but I don't see how to shorten it... I didn't understand  
mathcounterexamples.net's comment, so it would be nice to see it as an answer.